# What should I do when I think my answer has been incorrectly erased by a moderator?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderation

It is recommended if you have a similar answer to two dissimilar questions, that you tailor it for each question. In this case. I gave two different answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62880185/9077457), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62880436/9077457) & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62880268/9077457)) to two different questions, which were only similar in the fact that I reused the same sample code (and same first phrase) which was valid for both questions. However, I added multiple other comments related with each answer.

[image]

I believe these answers were deleted in error. Especially since the first one received very good reviews:

[image]

So… What is the correct way to report this problem?

There was a third (also tailored) answer with the same sample code. However, since I updated the code recently and missed one of them and the fact that there were three and not two in which I reused the same sample code.

So the claim becomes that even if it was to be considered that the other questions was similar enough to be removed, it still not nice to remove the one with many comments and upvotes and leave the nearly unseen one.

Comment: I'd suggest you try rewriting this post _without_ the insults.  It would probably get a better reception.  Insulting and slinging accusations at someone is no way to ask for a mistake to be corrected.

Comment: I have to say that I wonder how Martijn ended up on those answers and then deleting them. Are you sure this are the only two answers that got deleted or are there more in this set?

Comment: Nope, You're right. There was a third one and I missed it, because, I updated the code and I missed the third one. I'm updating the post

Comment: Don't add "EDIT".. just edit your post as if the current version is the one you want to be published. Think of it as the second (or third..) edition of the post. People can look at the revision history if they want to know what's been edited. (You don't read a book in the second revision with "EDIT" put in all kinds of places .. or hand in a school paper or post articles with "EDIT" :-)

Comment: @Camion I've undeleted the first post but not 100% on undeleting the second - I think Martijn's advice still stands for that one.

Comment: [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post)

Comment: “Only in rare occasions, like if editing an (old) question invalidates many existing answers”

Comment: Pointing to commentary you upvotes, as proof the answer was well received, is a little strange. Only one of those comments got an upvote other then your own. Why are you submitting the same answer to multiple questions, if you have already answered a question, and that answer that you submitted already answers a new question it’s a duplicate.

Comment: That's not the same answer, @SecurityHound. Only the sample code was the same. I just reused a complete working example which was valid for all three questions. - and I upvoted them for thanking them for recognizing them the interest of the solution I provided. And about the fact that there are so few reactions, may i point the fact that there are 7 years between the question and my answer ? There are just not many people with this problem. That's all.

Comment: @JonClements, I modified the second answer because I believe it was important to at least provide a link to a working solution (since I desperately struggled to find one) - but it doesn't seem to be accepted. Would you care providing feedback on it ?

Comment: How comes that all the comments have been deleted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835302/how-to-update-matplotlibs-imshow-window-interactively/62880185#62880185...

Comment: @Camion Probably because they mostly served as thanks for the answer, but you'd have to ask a moderator to know for sure.

Comment: @RyanM : No, they didn't MOSTLY served as thanks (there was a screen shot in the post) They thanked me indeed, but the first one underlined that unlike the others it was a standalone working solution. The second one stressed the importance of the pixel trick, and the third one gave me a hint for another solution I didn't know about.

Answer (score 6):

You've got a few options:

#### Flag the post for moderator attention

Use the "Flag" link below the post to request that the answer be undeleted, using the "in need of moderator intervention" option.

#### Post on Meta

Post a [support](/questions/tagged/support)[deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers)[specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer) question asking the community to evaluate if the deletion was correct.  Lots of moderators also frequent Meta, and will probably undelete your post if it's warranted.

### For either option, you should:

- Explain why you believe the post was incorrectly deleted. Perhaps a moderator looked too quickly and missed some aspect of your answer—remember that Stack Overflow gets thousands of flags a day, and moderators are volunteers.
- Not insult the moderator, site users, etc.
- Not throw around accusations of abuse, incompetence, etc.  If you really, truly believe a moderator has deliberately abused their power, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/165261) for how to handle that.

Comment: *Not insult the moderator, site users, etc.*  ... oh, come on. That is the only reason we visit  Meta, right? Right? Right!

Comment: Sometimes seems like that @rene :p

Comment: Yep... I missed the flag option, but there is no way to add comments, there... ?

Comment: @Camion if you use the "in need of moderator intervention" flag - you get a text box you can describe "why" into...

Comment: The other option is the Contact Us form at the bottom of every page. That goes to community mangers directly. It's slow, but mods answer to CMs. Just be aware that simpler disputes tend to get deferred to mods. That course is more for when you feel the moderator is misbehaving.